# Как правильно сформировать запрос к функции mysql через php?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть функция mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ukm_server`@`localhost` FUNCTION `acc_get_current_balance`(accId INTEGER(11)) RETURNS decimal(20,2)
    READS SQL DATA
    COMMENT 'Получает текущий баланс по счету'
BEGIN
      DECLARE res DECIMAL(20,2);

      SET res = 0.0;

      select IFNULL(balance,0.0) INTO res
      FROM `local_auth_account_journal`
      where account_id = accId
      order by date DESC , id DESC LIMIT 1;

      RETURN IFNULL(res,0.0);
END
```

как мне правильно передать значние accId и получить результат?
var_dump выдает

```
 object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

Нехватает опыта работы с php чтобы сформировать правильный запрос

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT acc_get_current_balance ('accId')");

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row;
}
```

пытался вместо accID прописать id к примеру 23, но ничего невыходит. Делал совсем по другому но тоже вообще ничего не вышло

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = 123;
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT acc_get_current_balance ({$id})");    
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row;
}
```

Выводить результат нужно вот так.

Comment: с этим разобрались, но видимо по функции я ничего не передалю т.к. результат ничего не выдает NULL

Comment: `$id = 123;
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT acc_get_current_balance ({$id})");`

Comment: Ну результат такой же ArrayNULL  выставил рабочие айди и ничего

Comment: Это конечно лучше чем у автора, но в коде опечатка.

Comment: @Ипатьев непосдкажите в чем может быть проблема? не видит ничего NULL возвращает, а хотя там сумма должна быть

Comment: @reddyk я вижу по этим двум вопросам что тут не одна проблема а примерно 500. И самая главная - а **зачем тут вообще функция** нужна? Все прекрасно можно сделать безо всяких функций

Comment: @reddyk $row - это массив, его просто так не вывести на экран. Попробуйте var_dump(). А также проверьте хранимую процедуру. возможно она возвращает не то, что вы ждете